Discrepancy between Python Power Spectrum and Swift Power Spectrum
I have a real signal HRV(t) and want to compute the power spectrum of it. The following are my Python and Swift implementations. The two implementations yield highly discrepant results.
import numpy as np

def power_spectrum(signal, fs=30):
    """
    Compute the power spectrum of a 1D real signal.

    Parameters:
    signal (array-like): Input signal
    fs (float): Sampling frequency (default is 30)

    Returns:
    f (numpy array): Frequencies corresponding to the power spectrum
    power (numpy array): Normalized power spectrum
    """
    # Length of the signal
    N = len(signal)

    # Frequency array
    f = np.arange(0, N // 2 + 1) * fs / N

    # Compute the FFT of the signal
    fft_result = np.fft.fft(signal)

    # Compute the power spectrum
    power = (1 / N) * np.abs(fft_result[:N // 2 + 1])**2

    # Normalize the power spectrum
    power = power / np.max(power)

    return f, power


public func powerSpectrum(_ input: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    // apply hamming window
    // window has slightly different precision than scipy.window.hamming (float vs double)
    var win = [Float](repeating: 0, count: input.count)
    vDSP_hamm_window(&win, vDSP_Length(input.count), 0)
    var input_windowed = [Float](repeating: 0, count: input.count)
    vDSP_vmul(win, 1, input, 1, &input_windowed, 1, vDSP_Length(win.count))
    symmetricZeroPad(signal: &input_windowed, length: 2048)
    var real = [Float](input_windowed)
    var imaginary = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: input_windowed.count)
    var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imaginary)
    let length = vDSP_Length(floor(log2(Float(input_windowed.count))))
    let radix = FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)
    let weights = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &splitComplex) { splitComplex in
      vDSP_fft_zip(weights!, splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))
    }
    //for index in 0..<input_windowed.count/2 { // Only half is needed since it's a real-to-complex FFT
    //  print("New Index \(index): Real = \(splitComplex.realp[index]), Imaginary = \(splitComplex.imagp[index])")
    //}
    // zvmags yields power spectrum: |S|^2
    var magnitudes = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: input_windowed.count)
    withUnsafePointer(to: &splitComplex) { splitComplex in
        magnitudes.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { magnitudes in
        vDSP_zvmags(splitComplex, 1, magnitudes.baseAddress!, 1, vDSP_Length(input_windowed.count))
        }
    }
    vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(weights)
    //magnitudes = magnitudes.map{ $0 / Float(input.count) }
    return magnitudes
}

func symmetricZeroPad(signal: inout [Float], length: Int) {
    let originalLength = signal.count
    let zerosToAdd = length - originalLength
    if zerosToAdd <= 0 {
      // No padding needed
      return
    }
    // Pad the signal symmetrically
    let leftZerosCount = zerosToAdd / 2
    let rightZerosCount = zerosToAdd - leftZerosCount
    signal = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: leftZerosCount) + signal + [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: rightZerosCount)
}

I have tried passing simple sine functions to it to test, but no luck. We tried single frequency sine waves and the output is a strict delta function in python, but not in swift.
Possible questions:

Is there spectral leakage?
Are the 2 implementations using different basis functions?
Is the data not being fed into Swift correctly?

Thanks!

As you've already noticed, the C API of the Accelerate library leads to some Swift code that's pretty hard to follow, and even harder to debug. I would suggest writing yourself a few helper extensions (like I demonstrate here) which help remove some of the pointer-related noise in this code. I'm fairly confident that in the process of testing each of those simple helpers, you'll find your issue.

You might also be interested in comparing against (or using) the really popular Surge package, which has an FFT implementation just like this: https://github.com/Jounce/Surge/blob/ac638794d4b02377e3628c1c8b1e07c2a15f1d52/Sources/Surge/Digital%20Signal%20Processing/FFT.swift#L25-L60
